# Unable to read two files simultaneously in java

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

Can anyone give me the working example of reading two files simultaneously through threads? and also what would be the best way to read them at one time.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

         new Runnable(new File("D:/test1.log"),"thread1");
         new Runnable(new File("D:/test2.log"),"thread2");
    }

    private static class Runnable implements Runnable {
        private File logFilePath;
        Thread runner;
        // you should inject the file path of the log file to watch
        public Runnable(File logFilePath,String threadName) {
            this.logFilePath = logFilePath;
            runner = new Thread(this, threadName);
            runner.start();
        }
               _____READ LOGIC HERE____
```

}

Program that generates logs.I am not using any close or flush .

```
public final class Slf4jSample {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Slf4jSample.class);
     static int i=0;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

            int delay = 0; // delay for 5 sec. 


            int period = 10000;  // repeat every sec.
            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Task here ...
                        logger.error("error"+i);
                        logger.warn("warn"+i);
                        logger.debug("debug"+i);
                            try{int i=0/0;
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                logger.error("Ecxeption"+i, e);
                            }

                   i++;




                    }
                }, delay, period);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your aim is from the short description, but I just want to warn you that reading files in parallel from a single hard disk is generally not a good idea, because the mechanical disk head needs to seek the next reading location and so reading with multiple threads will cause it to keep bouncing around and slow things down instead of speeding them up.

In case you want to read portions of files and process them in paralle, I recommend you to look at a single producer (to read the files sequentially) multiple consumer (to process the files) solution.

**Edit**: If you insist on using multiple readers, you should probably change your code like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

     new Thread(new ThreadTask(new File("D:/test1.log")),"thread1").start();
     new Thread(new ThreadTask(new File("D:/test2.log")),"thread2").start();
}

private static class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private File logFilePath;        

    // you should inject the file path of the log file to watch
    public ThreadTask(File logFilePath) {
        this.logFilePath = logFilePath;
    }

    public void run() {
        // read file
    }
}
```

Comment: But the thing is that these files are continuously changing.And i need to get updated data every time.

Comment: @raghav, Ok, I've posted an edit with how to make your program work.

Comment: i am trying this..will let u know

Comment: What happened was that when i stopped the program that is generating the file which was not printed,the output came.

Comment: So you have another program that generates the file?

Comment: Two programs are generating two files and one is reading those two files simultaneously..which is not happening .pls help

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the other programs? A file write will not be written to the disk until either flush or close is called. I think have the suspicion that you are only calling close at the end of the two programs and so the program reading the file does not see their changes until they are finished. Try to call flush on the output stream every time you write something.

Answer (score 3):

You have to instantiate a thread object like `Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(.....))`
and pass runnable object in Thread's constructor. 
Then calling start method on thread object will start separate thread and calls Runnable's run method.

You shouldn't be creating new threads inside Runnable's constructor.